# Why is it bad to use vectors when creating a matrix class?

Tags: c++, c++11

For my matrix class, I did:

```
template<typename T, std::uint32_t Height, std::uint32_t Width>
class Matrix
{
    private:
        std::array<std::array<T, Width>, Height> Elements;
        static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, "Argument T must be of arithmetic type.");

    public:
        Matrix();
        Matrix(T* Data);
        Matrix(T** Data);
        Matrix(T Data[Height][Width]);
        Matrix(const std::array<std::array<T, Width>, Height> &Data);

        inline int size() {return Width * Height;}
        inline const int size() const {return Width * Height;}

        inline int width() {return Width;}
        inline const int width() const {return Width;}

        inline int height() {return Height;}
        inline const int height() const {return Height;}

        std::array<T, Width>& operator[](int Index);
        const std::array<T, Width>& operator[](int Index) const;

        Matrix& operator = (const Matrix &M);

        Matrix& operator + (const Matrix &M);

        Matrix& operator - (const Matrix &M);

        Matrix& operator * (const Matrix &M);
};

template<typename T, std::uint32_t Height, std::uint32_t Width>
Matrix<T, Height, Width>::Matrix() {std::memset(&Elements, 0, sizeof(T) * Width * Height);}

template<typename T, std::uint32_t Height, std::uint32_t Width>
Matrix<T, Height, Width>::Matrix(T* Data) {if (Data) std::memcpy(&Elements, Data, sizeof(T) * Width * Height);}

template<typename T, std::uint32_t Height, std::uint32_t Width>
Matrix<T, Height, Width>::Matrix(T** Data) {if (Data) std::memcpy(&Elements, &Data[0][0], sizeof(T) * Width * Height);}

template<typename T, std::uint32_t Height, std::uint32_t Width>
Matrix<T, Height, Width>::Matrix(T Data[Height][Width]) {std::memcpy(&Elements, &Data[0][0], sizeof(T) * Width * Height);}

template<typename T, std::uint32_t Height, std::uint32_t Width>
Matrix<T, Height, Width>::Matrix(const std::array<std::array<T, Width>, Height> &Data) {std::memcpy(&Elements, &Data[0][0], sizeof(T) * Width * Height);}

template<typename T, std::uint32_t Height, std::uint32_t Width>
std::array<T, Width>& Matrix<T, Height, Width>::operator[](int Index) {return Elements[Index];}

template<typename T, std::uint32_t Height, std::uint32_t Width>
const std::array<T, Width>& Matrix<T, Height, Width>::operator[](int Index) const {return Elements[Index];}
```

because I read online and many comments saying not to use vectors and to instead use an array OR use std::valarray..

Now the reason I'm asking is because I want to re-write my matrix class so that I don't have to keep doing: `Matrix<Type, Width, Height>` every time.. I'd rather do that once in the constructor and not have to type that out for every single function.. As above. For example, I have to write out that long template declaration for each function AND for each Matrix argument. ALso I was not sure how to remove the resize/pushback for the vector so that when the user indexes the vector, they won't be able to resize it so I used arrays.

I was going to use a 1D array and index it doing (I * Width + J) but then I lose my [][] operator.

Is it bad to use vector of vectors? Any ideas to improve my class and keep it RAII conformant? I don't quite understand how to use valarray and the above is annoying to maintain. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Where did you read that? It’s wrong. Also, providing `[][]` [is a bad idea](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/matrix-array-of-array.html), and your array constructor doesn’t do what you think it’s doing (it’s not an array, the signature is equivalent to the `**` one, you are redeclaring that constructor). Finally, use the typesafe `std::copy` and not `std::memcpy`.

Comment: Its already row major order so the [][] is not a bad idea :S
Its two different constructors :S One allows:  double M[4][4]; The other allows  &M[0][0];  Without the array[Height][Width] Constructor, I cannot do Matrix(M); I'd have to do Matrix &M. Just a convenience is all. And yeah I'll use the std::copy.  It was a post here on stack overflow that said to use valarray because it was designed for math and vector keeps the size for each index or something like that.

Comment: That link is right, but only for naive `[][]`.  `[a]` should return a slice object, and `[b]` on a slice should call the equivalent of `(a,b)` on the parent matrix.  Such a slice object is about 10 lines long and works with *any* matrix implementation, and `Matrix::operator[]` is a one liner.  I can then augment the slice to be iterable.  Or augment `operator[]` to take a closure...

Comment: No, it’s a still bad idea, it does not matter whether it’s row major or not. Here are more arguments since you’re not convinced: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/matrix-c-style-subscript.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's true that a vector of vectors is not the best approach.  Assuming the data is rectangular (not jagged), there is some inefficiency in the allocations done by the vector-of-vectors approach, not to mention it prevents the somewhat common "reshape" operation ("treat my 2x3 matrix as 3x2 or 6x1 without copying").

> I was going to use a 1D array and index it doing (I * Width + J) but then I lose my [][] operator.

Sure, use a 1D vector.  That's great.  Then you can resize it, reshape it, etc., and have near-optimal performance for many operations.  And you keep RAII.

But you don't want to lose the ability to double-subscript (`[x][y]`)?  OK.  Just make your `operator[]` return a proxy object (which you implement).  The proxy will have its own `operator[]` which will operate on the second axis.  That is, the first `[]` will return a lightweight object which knows just enough to implement the second `[]`.

Comment: I like the idea of the proxy but I would not be able to return just one dimension no?  For example:

`double V[4] = matrx[0]  Returns row 0`. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine to use `vector<T>` for the backing store for your dense matrix class, but use one `vector<T>` and not the naive `vector<vector<T>>`.  Also make width, height and row/column major-ordering a runtime property of your matrix class.

The problem with `vector<vector<T>>` is that it will use N dynamic allocations, where N is the number of rows or columns.  Keeping the matrix stored in one dimension-major order block is more efficient as it uses 1 dynamic allocation.

Also by making the row/column major-ordering a runtime property, your transpose operation is constant-time.

For the actual matrix operations on your class there is a standard interface called BLAS that you can pass the backing store of your operands and result instances.  There are highly optimized BLAS implementations for every platform that use very low-level performance features of specific CPUs, and are much faster then what can be expressed in standard C++.

Comment: with compile time constant dimensions, `std::array` would be even finer than `std::vector`.

Comment: @phresnel: It's not really practical.  For the vast majority of matrix classes, the dimensions are stored as a runtime property, and the code generated reads and adapts to the dimensions at runtime - rather than generating code for each possible matrix size.  The performance gain by compiling out the dimensions is really quite minimal in most cases.  The exception to this is extremely small matricies, which usually have fixed specialized functions.

Comment: `the dimensions are stored as a runtime property` -> But not here. There are valid usecases where the dimensions are limited and known, e.g. in computer graphics. In the runtime case, you are right of course; however, I am arguing wrt to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a 1D array you can still implement the [][] operator, giving up a little security.

Let's say you're internal data is a T*(the most basic form). You can return the pointer to the fist element of a row:

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
    private:
        int height_, width_;
        T* data_;
    public:
        Matrix(int height, int width):
                height_(height),
                width_(width) {
            data_ = new T[height * width];
            std::fill(data_, data_ + height * width, T());
        }
        T* operator[](const int &row) { // i'm returning a pointer to the start of the row
            return data_ + width_ * row;
        }

        const T* operator[](const int &row) const {
            return data_ + width_ * row;
        }
};

int main() {
    Matrix<int> M(5, 5);

    M[3][3] = 1;
    M[3][5] = 2; // this is bad but will work and actually fill the next cell

    std::cout << M[4][0] << std::endl;
}
```

This will print 2