# Boost 3D vector

Tags: c++

I have declared a 3D vector `vector<vector<vector<boost::variant<string, float>>>> masterList;` which is going be filled with heterogeneous data (strings & float) is this the correct way? because I'm facing problem later with the instruction `masterList.push_back(tokens);` whereby I defined `std::vector<vector<string>> tokens;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vector of variants is what you need to store; this is not compatible with a vector of one of the variant's types.  In other words, you could do this:

```
vector<vector<vector<boost::variant<string, float>>>> masterList;
std::vector<vector<boost::variant<string, float>>> tokens;
masterList.push_back(tokens);
```

But if your data is such that the "variance" only happens at the outer dimension, you could instead do this:

```
vector<boost::variant<vector<vector<string>>, vector<vector<float>>>> masterList;
std::vector<vector<string>> tokens;
masterList.push_back(tokens);
```

You might also reconsider whether you need the full flexibility (and concomitant overhead) of a vector of vectors of vectors.  If your data is rectangular (not jagged), you can improve the situation as outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17005753/4323